# I would like to change my heart shape into Triangle shape. But can't get path svg code?

Tags: html, css, svg, path, shapes

I have this heart shape, with some path coordinates. But I will like to have a triangle instead, but I'm able to find the right coordinate code. Can Someone help me out? So, one of the heart shapes can be a Triangle instead?

Tried to change the heart shape code with this triangle code: M 6 3 L 0 12 H 12 Z. But then the triangle shape is not visible or doesn't show the shape then?

Hope for your help. Thanks!

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#textPath");

const a = document.documentElement,
  b = document.body,
  st = "scrollTop",
  sh = "scrollHeight",
  startOffset = 0;

const offsetOnScroll = (percent, startOffset) =>
  textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", percent * 10 + startOffset);

textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", startOffset);

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  let percent = ((a[st] || b[st]) / ((a[sh] || b[sh]) - a.clientHeight)) * 100;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => offsetOnScroll(percent * -1, startOffset));
});


/* number two; */
const textPathB = document.querySelector("#textPathB");
const aB = document.documentElement,
    bB = document.body,
    stB = "scrollTop",
    shB = "scrollHeight",
    startOffsetB = 0;
const offsetOnScrollB = (percent, startOffsetB) =>
    textPathB.setAttribute("startOffset", percent * 10 + startOffset);
    textPathB.setAttribute("startOffset", startOffset);
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    let percent = ((aB[stB] || bB[stB]) / ((aB[shB] || bB[shB]) - aB.clientHeight)) * 100;
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => offsetOnScrollB(percent * -1, startOffset));
});
```

```css
/* heart shape */
.shape {
  fill: none;
  /* stroke: white; */
}

#heart {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#textPath {
  /* The font-size is really hacky, sorry :( */
  font-family: 'Till-Normal';
  --sizefactor: 1.112;
  font-size: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  letter-spacing: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  fill: var(--purple-full);
  font-weight: 800
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* background-color: palevioletred; */
}

/* 2 heart shape */
.shape1 {
  fill: none;
  /* stroke: white; */
}

#hearttwo {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#textPathB {
  /* The font-size is really hacky, sorry :( */
  font-family: 'Till-Normal';
  --sizefactor: 1.112;
  font-size: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  letter-spacing: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  fill: var(--purple-full);
  font-weight: 800
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* background-color: palevioletred; */
}
```

```html
<!-- Heart -->

  <div class="container1">
      <svg id="heart" data-name="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

          <path class="shape" id="shape" d="M-400 32 v-150 h200 a100,100 90 0,1 0,200 a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0 z" transform="rotate(225, 0, 0)"/>

          <text font-family="arial">
              <textPath xlink:href="#shape" id="textPath"> THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • </textPath>
          </text>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- Triangle -->
  <div class="container2">
      <svg id="hearttwo" data-name="hearttwo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

          <path class="shape1" id="shape1" d="M-400 32 v-150 h200 a100,100 90 0,1 0,200 a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0 z" transform="rotate(225, 0, 0)"/>

          <text font-family="arial">
              <textPath xlink:href="#shape1" id="textPathB"> THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • </textPath>
          </text>
      </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have tried editting it? Copy the d-path and edit in online in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Comment: Yes, I did, but the shape does not show up in the code. M 6 3 L 0 12 H 12 Z

Comment: Your SVG 'paperformat' ``viewBox`` is 400 x 400 pixels. So a **L**ine from **6,3** to **0,12** (that is all your path does)  will hardly be visible. You have to learn to draw SVG paths: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this triangle so far. You should take a look at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) and learn more about paths. And also from Danny '365CSI' Engelman's comment tinker with this svg editor [link](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) You should understand how path variables work. Issue here is, when you change the path variable, you must keep the x y axes in mind or it won't show up.

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#textPath");

const a = document.documentElement,
  b = document.body,
  st = "scrollTop",
  sh = "scrollHeight",
  startOffset = 0;

const offsetOnScroll = (percent, startOffset) =>
  textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", percent * 10 + startOffset);

textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", startOffset);

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  let percent = ((a[st] || b[st]) / ((a[sh] || b[sh]) - a.clientHeight)) * 100;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => offsetOnScroll(percent * -1, startOffset));
});


/* number two; */
const textPathB = document.querySelector("#textPathB");
const aB = document.documentElement,
    bB = document.body,
    stB = "scrollTop",
    shB = "scrollHeight",
    startOffsetB = 0;
const offsetOnScrollB = (percent, startOffsetB) =>
    textPathB.setAttribute("startOffset", percent * 10 + startOffset);
    textPathB.setAttribute("startOffset", startOffset);
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    let percent = ((aB[stB] || bB[stB]) / ((aB[shB] || bB[shB]) - aB.clientHeight)) * 100;
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => offsetOnScrollB(percent * -1, startOffset));
});
```

```css
/* heart shape */
.shape {
  fill: none;
  /* stroke: white; */
}

#heart {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#textPath {
  /* The font-size is really hacky, sorry :( */
  font-family: 'Till-Normal';
  --sizefactor: 1.112;
  font-size: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  letter-spacing: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  fill: var(--purple-full);
  font-weight: 800
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* background-color: palevioletred; */
}

/* 2 heart shape */
.shape1 {
  fill: none;
  /* stroke: white; */
}

#hearttwo {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#textPathB {
  /* The font-size is really hacky, sorry :( */
  font-family: 'Till-Normal';
  --sizefactor: 1.112;
  font-size: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  letter-spacing: calc(1em * var(--sizefactor));
  fill: var(--purple-full);
  font-weight: 800
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* background-color: palevioletred; */
}
```

```html
<!-- Heart -->

  <div class="container1">
      <svg id="heart" data-name="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

          <path class="shape" id="shape" d="M -200 -150 V 50 H -400 Z" transform="rotate(225, 0, 0)"/>

          <text font-family="arial">
              <textPath xlink:href="#shape" id="textPath"> THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • THE BLISS OF ADOPTION  • </textPath>
          </text>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- Triangle -->
  <div class="container2">
      <svg id="hearttwo" data-name="hearttwo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

          <path class="shape1" id="shape1" d="M -200 -150 V 50 H -400 Z" transform="rotate(225, 0, 0)"/>

          <text font-family="arial">
              <textPath xlink:href="#shape1" id="textPathB"> THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • THE ULTIMATE FAIRYTALE • </textPath>
          </text>
      </svg>
  </div>
```